# How can i make the JSON based array in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json, jsonp, kendo-ui

I would like to know how can we make the JSON based array using json_encode() PHP ;
The format of the array should be look like this.

```
callback([{"ProductID":1,"ProductName":"Chai","UnitPrice":18,"UnitsInStock":39,"Discontinued":false}])
```

When we need the this `header("Content-type: application/json");`

**UPDATE**

in above format you can see the format check the numeric values, json_encode not mention the double quotes the numeric values. I just want to configure the Mysql values on this format, like numeric value without double quotes, and string values with double quotes. We should have to configure mysql values on this format.

Thanks

Comment: Let me guess. You haven't even tried.

Comment: Yes, I tried a lot, but we are getting this in this style "http://www.octave-global.com/portal/tool/" but we need to implement it on this style. "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Products" ...... the main difference is ---------------callback([{"ProductID":1,"ProductName":"Chai"--------------- double quotes not in productID (http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Products in this url) and ID ------------callback([{"ID":"185","Title":"DISH Network"}-------------Double quotes is in ID  (http://www.octave-global.com/portal/tool/ in this url)........ we have to make the similar format for both the url.

Comment: @user1089288: Update your question instead of posting this in your comment. This is completely unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
$array = array(
    'ProductID'    => 1,
    'ProductName'  => 'Chai',
    'UnitPrice'    => 18,
    'UnitsInStock' => 39,
    'Discontinued' => false
);
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: how can we configure this with MYSQL values ?

Comment: Just replace the array variable as such -- $array = mysql_fetch_array($query); then output the header and the json_encode as stated above.

Answer (score 1):

**edit:** It appears you are trying to serve JSONP, not JSON. JSONP should be given the content type of `application/javascript` like this:

```
header("Content-type: application/javascript");
$json = json_encode(
    array(
        array(
            "ProductID"    => 1,
            "ProductName"  => "Chai",
            "UnitPrice"    => 18,
            "UnitsInStock" => 39,
            "Discontinued" => false
        )
    )
);
echo "callback({$json})";
```

Comment: how can we configure this with MYSQL values ?

Comment: If a numeric value is passed to json_encode, it will be encoded without quotes. If it is passed with quotes (i.e. a string, not a number), it will remain quoted in the encoded JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

the example on that page should tell you everything you need to know.